# Validate URL with advanced URL strings

Tags: objective-c

Working on an app that validates a URL before accepting the submission.

The follow code accepts simple urls such as www.google.com, but does not worth with more complex urls such as www.google.com/?test-test

```
- (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Comment: You are only scratching the surface. 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/427083

Answer (score 0):

Cited from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:):

> Return Value An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the URL
>   string was malformed or nil, returns nil.

You can test validity of URL by actually trying to make a `NSURL` object.

```
NSString* some_url1 = ...// your input
NSURL* u1 = [NSURL URLWithString:some_url1];
BOOL ok = u1 != nil;
```